# Access field from intermediary model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having a hard time trying to access a field from an intermediary model in DRF.

Let's see the related models:

```
class School(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_(u'Name'))

    staff_order = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_(u'Staff ordering'), through='StaffOrder', related_name='school_staff_order')

class User(AbstractUser):

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.username)

class StaffOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_(u'Staff ordering for this school'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Staff ordering')
```

Now what I'm expecting is being able to read order field from StaffOrder in when returning a QuerySet for users (StaffSerializer). Here are the Serializers:

```
class StaffRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StaffOrder
        fields = (
            'order',
        )


class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=75, required=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=75, required=True)
    order = StaffRoleSerializer(source='school_staff_order')

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

What is returned in order for the StaffSerializer is a Manager, instead of the order field from the StaffOrder model related with this User.

A JSON expected response for Staff would be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "username": "Denise",
    "email": "deniseburton@maximind.com",
    "order": 9
  },
  {
    "username": "Ina",
    "email": "inaburton@maximind.com",
    "order": 4
  }
]
```

I'd love to be able to also write this value from the serializer, but I can do that in the Viewset, but I really need to read this value in the Serializer itself...any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: your naming is so confusing. Why is there source=school_staff_order on order field? What does it refer to?

Comment: @zaphod100.10 That seems to be a requirement when mapping intermediary models in serializers. It maps to the related name in School.staff_order

Comment: shouldn't the field `staff_order` be named as `users` or `staff` on the school model? Because it is a many relation with users. And can you give an example of json you want?

Comment: @zaphod100.10 staff_order is just an index to know what staff should be displayed first, so I will probably sort it once I get it to return the correct value. I've updated so an expected JSON is on the description

Comment: One user cannot have one order. It is a many relationship. You have to specify the query which order value you want.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand that one user can have many staff orders. In your models you have defined it that way.

To get the json output you have specified in your question you need to query the StaffOrder objects instead of users.

```
class StaffOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')

    class Meta:
        model = StaffOrder
        fields = ('order', )
```

Use this serializer class in a list view:

```
class StaffOrderListApi(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StaffOrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # using distinct because same user can have multiple staff orders
        # based on your example it seems you want distinct users
        return StaffOrder.objects.all().distinct('user')
```

This will get you exactly the json you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just part of a much bigger app, I cannot return StaffOrders model. And yes, a User can have more than an entry in StaffOrder model, since a user can be in N schools, and may have a different order in each school. Regarding view, I'm using a view that inherits from NestedViewSetMixin and ModelViewSet. As I commented, this is a very simpliefied version of my current models, I cannot throw away my StaffSerializer and use your proposed StaffOrderSerializer, but I like the idea, thanks :)